# sudo rm -rf permission denied

Tags: linux, rsync, file-permissions, rm

I accidentally copied my entire disk with `rsync -a / ...` to my backup server. When trying to delete this backup with `sudo rm -rf backup_dir` I get a `permission denied` error on some sub directories of `backup_dir/run`, `backup_dir/sys` as well as on some files in docker volumes.
When trying to change the ownership of the files with `sudo chmod -R user:user` backup_dir`, I get the same error. Also changing the file permissions with` chmod -R 00775` does not work.

The `backup_dir` is mounted as cifs like this:
`//backup_server/backup on /mnt/backup type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=2.0,cache=strict,username=user,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,mapposix,rsize=65536,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,closetimeo=1,user=username)`.

I also tried mounting the `backup_dir` with `sshfs`: `user@backup_server:/backup on /mnt/backup type fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)` but I get the same `permission denied` errors.

For example `backup_dir/sys/power` is an empty directory which I cannot not delete. It has the following attributes: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 0 2023-12-22 13:31 power`.
Changing the ownership of the directory with `sudo chown user:user power` does not return an error but also has no effect (root stays the owner).

I think this is an issue with extended file permissions (e.g sticky bit). However I cannot list them since `lsattr` returns a `Operation not supported While reading flags on ./file` error.

How can I delete those files?

Comment: Try logging in directly to the server (ex. ssh) and remove the files from there, or see what `ls`, `lsattr`, `mount` say then

Comment: That does not work because I only have very limited shell.

Comment: I didn't think just viewing mount or `/proc/mounts` was usually locked down, but anything's possible. Asking the sysadmin should always work, as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

You could try to become root with `sudo su` and then taking ownership with  `chown -R your_username:your_group backup_dir`

The -R flag makes the operation recursive, applying changes to all files and subdirectories.

Comment: When doing that, I get the same permission denied error.

Comment: Is the filesystem maybe mounted with restrictions? Read only or immutable. Can you do `ls -l` for one file and provide the output

Comment: It is mounted by cifs (samba). I'm currently trying to mount it with a different method.

Comment: I tried mounting the backup_dir with cifs and sshfs. I amended the quest with the information.